# Is something wrong with this question stuck "offline for maintenance"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, server-maintenance

Something fishy is going on with one particular question: [No virtual method findViewHolderForPosition(I) when trying to click on RecyclerView item with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775782/no-virtual-method-findviewholderforpositioni-when-trying-to-click-on-recyclerv)

When I try to visit this question from my work laptop (which is on the corporate VPN in another state), it takes its time loading, only to produce a message:

> We are currently offline for maintenance. Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns into an extended outage, we will tweet updates from @StackStatus or post details on the status blog.

It's been doing this since I left work on Friday afternoon, so it's been a while.

That said, when I visit from my phone on my home network, it works fine. And other questions work fine on my work laptop as well. **Update:** Other questions did work fine on my work laptop on Friday after I saw this problem, but I'm now getting the maintenance message for all questions. Not sure if I was getting a cached version before or if the situation has actually gotten worse. I'm still able to access the site homepage and questions list, but not any actual questions on SO or Meta. Other SE sites seem to be working normally, and this is still only on my work laptop.

(If this is the wrong place to ask this, I apologize...I didn't see any indications that the @StackStatus Twitter account responds to tweets, and the [only help page I found mentioning support queries and bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) directed me here to Meta.)

Is something up with the site?

Comment: This site is the correct location for your question. I have to ask though: are you able to access other SO questions from your work laptop?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, I thought they did, although the don't seem to be working any more. Not sure if I was just getting cached copies of other questions before, or if the situation has actually degraded.

Comment: Recent Thread also probably related: '[Why is server maintenance scheduled at mid-day European time?](/q/418869)'...

Comment: FYI: We're tracking an issue that appears to be impacting a sub-set of users in the Chicago, IL area, resulting in the "offline for maintenance" page. Will update once we know more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've identified an issue with our CDN causing intermittent 503 errors for people in the Chicago area.

https://www.stackstatus.net/

Comment: Update: The issue has been resolved.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing service!